# Testing equality of two variables - one is entity reference

Tags: theming

I'm new to Drupal theming and twig, so apologies for asking a simple question, but it's driving me crazy. I can't find the solution.

I'm trying to test the equality of field from a Custom content type - field_program_level - that's an Entity reference type. field_program_level has two possible values : G and UG.

I've tried everything I know and my code doesn't work.  My current code is:

```
{% set yy = content.field_program_level[0]|render %} 
{% set graduate = 'G' %}
{% if yy is same as(graduate) %}
<p> Success! yy was created and equal to {{ yy }} </p>
{% else %}
<p> Failure! {{ yy }} does not = {{ graduate }} </p>
{% endif %}
```

I'm assuming that because field_program_level is a entity reference it's some type of array or object.

yy = {{ yy }}

outputs "G" as it should, but "is same as" fails.

I tried using {{ node.field_program_level.0.value }} but it doesn't work. I've also tried using filters |render and |trim.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `node` object instead of the `content` render array is a good idea, but a reference field doesn't contain a value. You probably want to test against the label of the referenced entity:

```
{% set yy = node.field_program_level.0.entity.label %} 
{% set graduate = 'G' %}
{% if yy is same as(graduate) %}
```

Comment: That did it... thank you. I have to say I'm not fond of Twig.